# Using ExtraData to send params from the authorization server back to the client

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, access-token

I've been trying to use the `ExtraData` property on the `EndUserAuthorizationSuccessBase` class to send extra params back to the client. I first needed to send back the username but then I figured out I could get it from the `AccessToken`. Now I need to send back the user's choice of whether to keep her signed in or not (so I would create a persistent cookie or one that expires in 30 minutes). Unfortunately, I could not get this to work properly. What happens is that when I call the token's endpoint on my authorization server the `OutgoingWebResponse` indicates failure saying `invalid token` in the `Body` of the message. Below is my code:

```
    public ActionResult Login(String username, String password, String rememberMe, String keepMeSignedIn)
    {
        var request = Session[SESSION_KEY] as EndUserAuthorizationRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            Guid siteId = Guid.Parse(request.ClientIdentifier);
            Boolean isAuthenticated = this._identityProviderManager.Authenticate(siteId, "FA", username, password);
            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                var serviceHost = new AuthorizationServerHost();
                var authorizationServer = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServer(serviceHost);
                var approvalMessage = authorizationServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(request, username, request.Scope);
                approvalMessage.ExtraData[GlobalConstants.Misc.KeepMeSignedIn] = Convert.ToString(keepMeSignedIn != null && keepMeSignedIn.Equals("on", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                return authorizationServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(approvalMessage).AsActionResult();

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Token Endpoint**

```
    public ActionResult GetToken()
    {
        AuthorizationServerHost serverHost = new AuthorizationServerHost();
        AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServer(serverHost);
        OutgoingWebResponse response = authorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest(Request);
        ActionResult result = response.AsActionResult();
        return result;
    }
```

Why is that happening?